# Why is my modal backdrop above the modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

Below you find a situation where the *specified* z-index of the modal is higher than the z-index of the modal-backdrop. Still, there are many situations that the backdrop will be on top of the modal. So, the user cannot access the modal. You find an example below in picture and code.

[image]

What are the rules for getting a modal always on top of the backdrop? Especially, I am looking for the 'position' options for the 'container' class. I simplified my issue by just using a simple container. In reality that container may have different positions. I used jQuery just to simplify the context.

Below you find HTML with 4 examples when a modal backdrop appears to be 'above' the modal. An example is:

Switching the backdrop 'off' is NOT a solution.

I read [this great post](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/) and [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context), but find it hard to apply to the deserved cases. I experimented with the 'stack context' in combination with placing the modal-divs inside or outside the container-div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal({
      backdrop: true
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  z-index: 85;
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 1: container position: relative; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 2: container position: absolute; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Less important ... */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 3: container position: relative; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 4: container position: absolute; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  position: absolute;
}

.modal {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal and backdrops</h2>
    <p>Simulate a backdrop that overrules a modal</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Overlay</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This modal has a overlay.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Updates**: removing the z-index from the modal is indeed correct. It will however not solve the current issue.

Digging deeper, I have these 2 screenshots. Before launching the popup. And after launching the popup; the modal-backdrop is dynamically added near the end of the DOM. I guess outside the context stack of the modal-div.

This is a situation inherited in maintaining a complex web page. The modal-div is inside a library component. The library comp is positioned with 'relative'.

[image]

... and after launching the popup:

[image]

Comment: This may be of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context It's important to keep the modal and its backdrop in the same stacking context.  It's been long enough since i used jQuery that I'm not sure whether its `modal()` does that acceptably in all circumstances

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting the container element's position? That's the source of the problem.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. _Why do you have absolute positioning on the container?_  Remove that and the problem goes away. Absolute positioning is the cause of a great many problems for newer developers and should generally be avoided.

Comment: We 'inherited' the code, I am just the maintainer of the code ... :-(  NOTICE: also the 'relative' position of the (simplified) container runs in the same issues. Just tried to find a good rule based on situations .

Comment: "i.c.m."? Please don't use acronyms or abbreviations in questions. Just [edit] your question and type out the whole phrase.

Comment: There is no need for .modal to have a z-index since it is inside .modal-backdrop. z-index is context-based: it applies only to the context the element belongs to. A new context is created every time an element has a non-static position. Hence .modal-backdrop is a context and .modal does not need a z-index. Just remove it.

Comment: That fact that you inherited the code doesn't explain why you can't _modify_ the code. Are you saying you're unable to remove that rule from the element for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to slightly change the `backdrop` function in the bootstrap v3.4.1 modal, and insert `.modal-backdrop` directly into `.modal`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/f17f882df292b29323f1e1da515bd16f326cee4a/js/modal.js#L186
    
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.backdrop = function (callback) {
     var Modal = $.fn.modal.Constructor /* + */
   var that = this
     var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

    if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
      var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

      this.$backdrop = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .addClass('modal-backdrop ' + animate)
        // .appendTo(this.$body)
          this.$element.append(this.$backdrop); /* + */

      this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        // if (this.ignoreBackdropClick) {
          // this.ignoreBackdropClick = false
          // return
        // }
        // if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return
          if (e.target !== this.$backdrop[0]) return /* + */
        this.options.backdrop == 'static'
          ? this.$element[0].focus()
          : this.hide()
      }, this))

      if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

      this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

      if (!callback) return

      doAnimate ?
        this.$backdrop
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', callback)
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        callback()

    } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
      this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

      var callbackRemove = function () {
        that.removeBackdrop()
        callback && callback()
      }
      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
        this.$backdrop
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', callbackRemove)
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        callbackRemove()

    } else if (callback) {
      callback()
    }
  }
    
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal({
      backdrop: true
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  z-index: 85;
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 1: container position: relative; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 2: container position: absolute; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Less important ... */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 3: container position: relative; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 4: container position: absolute; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  position: absolute;
}

.modal {
  background-color: red;
}

.modal .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: green;
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal and backdrops</h2>
    <p>Simulate a backdrop that overrules a modal</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Overlay</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This modal has a overlay.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any other modals will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Give position relative or absolute, Whatever works for you, To the class .modal, Then the z-index will works on modal.

Comment: In our situation, the modal-div is within the container-dev. Then this solution does not help. This may be helpful if the modal is placed outside the container-div when other solutions fail.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if you remove all the z-index from the model and container, then the model and its overlay are working fine and clickable for the button and close icon, respectively.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal and backdrops</h2>
    <p>Simulate a backdrop that overrules a modal</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Overlay</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>This modal has a overlay.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

change the backdrop color as per your requirement.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: green; 
}
```

Use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myBtn").click(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal({
            backdrop: true
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instade of using z-index you can add position absolute to your modal

Comment: In our situation, the modal-div is within the container-dev. Then this solution does not help. This may be helpful if the modal is placed outside the container-div when other solutions fail.

Answer (score 0):

Looking all your .container div, you can move modal out of container.  if this is can be done, this will solve all the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal({
      backdrop: true
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  z-index: 85;
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 1: container position: relative; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 2: container position: absolute; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
  /* Less important ... */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 3: container position: relative; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  /* Backdrop overrules: situation 4: container position: absolute; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
  position: absolute;
}

.modal {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal and backdrops</h2>
    <p>Simulate a backdrop that overrules a modal</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay</button>
  </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Overlay</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This modal has a overlay.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Alas, not possible. Inside a library component a modal is used ...

Answer (score 0):

Just move div.Modal out of div.container.
Change some css; **(use !important)**

- remove -> .modal background-color: red;
- add -> .modal-content { background-color: red !important; }
- add -> .modal-backdrop { background-color: green !important; }

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myBtn").click(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal({
          backdrop: true
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
.container {
      z-index: 85;
      /* Backdrop overrules: situation 1: container position: relative; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
      /* Backdrop overrules: situation 2: container position: absolute; && modal position: no position with modal inside container-div */
      /* Less important ... */
      /* Backdrop overrules: situation 3: container position: relative; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
      /* Backdrop overrules: situation 4: container position: absolute; && modal-div position: static with modal outside container-div */
      position: absolute;
    }

    .modal {
      z-index: 100;
    }

    .modal-content {
      background-color: red !important;
    }

    .modal-backdrop {
      background-color: green !important;
      z-index: 90;
    }
```

```html
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal and backdrops</h2>
        <p>Simulate a backdrop that overrules a modal</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay</button>
      </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Overlay</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This modal has a overlay.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Alas, not possible. Inside a library component a modal is used and started.

Comment: Your "z-index" destroys the structure. You can remove all "z-index" code and try again.